# TypeError: Not JSON Serializable: <module 'tensorflow' from '/path/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'

Tags: json, tensorflow, keras, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to save the best model through the keras checkpoint callback. However, save model returns a "Not Jason serialisable" error similar, but not exactly the same, as some of the other issues previously raised, which are supposedly resolved by a tf-nightly install. I cannot provide the one-hot-encoded input data.

I have installed the tensorflow-nightly, but the problem still remains. I have also directly used the save.model keras function, which returns the same error, but also a file which is entirely filled with columns of zeros.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras import initializers
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, GRU
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.utils.training_utils import multi_gpu_model
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.utils import plot_model
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
import h5py
import logging
import time

ts = time.time()
time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
log_dir ="path/logs/{}/server_0".format(date)

if not os.path.isdir(log_dir):
    os.makedirs(log_dir)

#Visualize Model
def visualize_model(model):
    SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog="dot", format="svg"))
    return plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, 
                      to_file=os.path.join(log_dir, "network_architecture_{}.svg".format(time)))


def keras_1D_CNN():

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(input_shape=(253,21), 
                            kernel_initializer="he_uniform", 
                            bias_initializer=initializers.Constant(0.1), 
                            nb_filter=256,
                            filter_length=2,
                            padding="same",
                            activation="relu", 
                            dilation_rate=2, 
                            name='conv-1D_1'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='BatchNorm_1'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1, name='MaxPool1D_1'))

    model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding="same", 
                            kernel_initializer="he_uniform", 
                            bias_initializer=initializers.Constant(0.1), 
                            dilation_rate=3, 
                            name='conv-1D_2'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='BatchNorm_2'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=1, name='MaxPool1D_2'))

    model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding="same", 
                            kernel_initializer="he_uniform", 
                            bias_initializer=initializers.Constant(0.1), 
                            dilation_rate=4, 
                            name='conv-1D_3'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='BatchNorm_3'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=1, name='MaxPool1D_3'))

    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5,
                             recurrent_dropout=0.2), input_shape=(241, 1)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(128, activation='relu'), name='Dense_1'))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.4, name='TimeDistributed-Dropout_1 = 0.4')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation='relu'), name='Dense_2'))
    model.add(Flatten(name='Flatten'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='Dropout_1'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', 
                    kernel_initializer="he_uniform", 
                    bias_initializer=initializers.Constant(0.1), 
                    name='Dense_3'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='Dropout_2'))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Sigmoid-layer'))

    visualize_model(model)
    model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)

    opt = keras.optimizers.Adadelta()
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join(log_dir, "TensorBoard_{}".format(time)), 
                              write_graph=True, write_grads=True, batch_size=2048)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    with open(os.path.join(log_dir, 'model_summary{}.txt'.format(time)),'w') as fh:
        model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: fh.write(x + '\n'))
    checkpoint_filepath = os.path.join(log_dir, "best-model-{}".format(time) + "_{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5")
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath, monitor='val_loss', 
                                   verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode="min")
    earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100, verbose=1)
    CNN_history = model.fit(partial_seq_train, 
              partial_label_train, 
              epochs=1000, 
              batch_size=2048, 
              validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[tensorboard, earlystopper, checkpoint])

    return (model, CNN_history, results)
CNN_1D_model = keras_1D_CNN()
```

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4d0435c2448d> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('time', '')
----> 2 CNN_1D_model = keras_1D_CNN()
      3 CNN_history_dict = CNN_1D_model[1].history
      4 CNN_history_dict.keys()
      5 print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (CNN_1D_model[0].metrics_names[1], CNN_1D_model[2][1]*100))

<ipython-input-21-2bf565bb8ec7> in keras_1D_CNN()
    100               epochs=1000,
    101               batch_size=2048,
--> 102               validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[tensorboard, earlystopper, checkpoint], verbose=0)
    103 #     CNN_history = model.fit(partial_seq_train,
    104 #               partial_label_train,

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1038                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1040 
   1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    215                         for l, o in zip(out_labels, val_outs):
    216                             epoch_logs['val_' + l] = o
--> 217         callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    218         if callback_model.stop_training:
    219             break

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
     77         logs = logs or {}
     78         for callback in self.callbacks:
---> 79             callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
     80 
     81     def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    444                             self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
    445                         else:
--> 446                             self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
    447                     else:
    448                         if self.verbose > 0:

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1088             raise NotImplementedError
   1089         from ..models import save_model
-> 1090         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1091 
   1092     def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True):

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    380 
    381     try:
--> 382         _serialize_model(model, f, include_optimizer)
    383     finally:
    384         if opened_new_file:

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in _serialize_model(model, f, include_optimizer)
     82     model_config['class_name'] = model.__class__.__name__
     83     model_config['config'] = model.get_config()
---> 84     model_config = json.dumps(model_config, default=get_json_type)
     85     model_config = model_config.encode('utf-8')
     86     f['model_config'] = model_config

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in get_json_type(obj)
     72             return obj.__name__
     73 
---> 74         raise TypeError('Not JSON Serializable: %s' % (obj,))
     75 
     76     from .. import __version__ as keras_version

TypeError: Not JSON Serializable: <module 'tensorflow' from '/d/harpy1/s/python/v3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'>```
````

Comment: Are these your actual imports? Any import related to tf.keras?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I updated the question.